# How to get total size of a docker image by docker API properly?

Tags: docker

I want to get total size of a docker image by docker API, such as `GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>` which is described here [docker spec](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image-manifest)

I got a list of layers with size, such as this [example](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/manifest-v2-2.md#image-manifest), I add up these sizes but got a number which is smaller than `docker images` command show, as i know the docker registry stores these layers files as gzipped tar files, so this sum should be smaller than the size which is showed by `docker images` command.

How to get the total image size properly by docker API?
I want to get the same size as `docker images` command show.

Comment: What command have you used?

Comment: @Rao, hi, i use `docker images` command to get a image size

Comment: I was asking about GET call command that you mention in the beginning of the post which you are comparing against docker images.

Comment: @Rao, i use this HTTP API: `GET http://registry:5000/v2/library/mysql/manifests/5.6`

Answer (score 9):

### TLDR

The size given by `docker images` is the **uncompressed size** of the image installed **locally**, you can only get **from the registry** the size of the **compressed images** (for each architecture and if you want for each layer).

### From a local image

The size given by `docker images` is the **uncompressed size of an image on your system**.

```sh
# getting the size of alpine:latest
docker images alpine:latest --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} -> {{.Size}}"

# alpine:latest -> 5.57MB
```

You can get the same information if you download the image `locally` by using the `docker inspect` command.

```
docker inspect alpine:latest | jq '.[].Size' 

# 5573013
```

### From a registry

As far as I know you can only get **from a registry the compressed size of an image**.

```
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/alpine/tags/ | \
        jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .full_size'

# 2796860
```

In fact the registry can give the size of the image for **each architecture**.

```sh
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/alpine/tags/ | \
        jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .images[] | {architecture: .architecture, size: .size}'

# {
#   "architecture": "arm",
#   "size": 2405675
# }
# {
#   "architecture": "arm",
#   "size": 2601912
# }
# {
#   "architecture": "386",
#   "size": 2791407
# }
# {
#   "architecture": "s390x",
#   "size": 2565829
# }
# {
#   "architecture": "ppc64le",
#   "size": 2803218
# }
# {
#   "architecture": "amd64",
#   "size": 2796860
# }
# {
#   "architecture": "arm64",
#   "size": 2706555
# }
```

You can even get the detail of the **compressed size of each layer** by using the `docker manifest inspect` experimental command.

```sh
# activate experimental mode
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled 

docker manifest inspect -v alpine:latest | \
       jq '.[] | select(.Descriptor.platform.architecture=="amd64") | .SchemaV2Manifest.layers[].size'

# 2796860
```

If there is multiple layers you can sum them. Here is an example with `jupyter/base-notebook:latest`

```sh
# getting the size through the API
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/jupyter/base-notebook/tags | \ 
        jq '.results[] | select(.name=="latest") | .full_size'

# 187647701

# summing each layer
docker manifest inspect jupyter/base-notebook:latest | jq '[.layers[].size] | add' 

# 187647701
```

Comment: `jq: error: Could not open file .[].Size: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the image size from `docker images` output is inaccurate, because it's a human readable size.
e.g.:

`5573013  -> 5573013.0/1000/1000 -> 5.57 MB`

Let's have a peek at the source code for Docker.

```
// ImageAPIClient defines API client methods for the images
type ImageAPIClient interface {
    ImageList(ctx context.Context, options types.ImageListOptions) ([]types.ImageSummary, error)
}
type ImageSummary struct {
    Containers int64 `json:"Containers"`
    Created int64 `json:"Created"`
    ID string `json:"Id"`
    Labels map[string]string `json:"Labels"`
    ParentID string `json:"ParentId"`
    RepoDigests []string `json:"RepoDigests"`
    RepoTags []string `json:"RepoTags"`
    SharedSize int64 `json:"SharedSize"`
    Size int64 `json:"Size"`
    VirtualSize int64 `json:"VirtualSize"`
}
```

As you can see, the `ImageList` method returns ImageSummarys, and the size is accurate, how does the **cli** print the images list?
That's what the `imageContext` does, it converts the attribute to string and prints the `SIZE` like follows:

```
func (c *imageContext) Size() string {
    return units.HumanSizeWithPrecision(float64(c.i.Size), 3)
}
// HumanSizeWithPrecision allows the size to be in any precision,
// instead of 4 digit precision used in units.HumanSize.
func HumanSizeWithPrecision(size float64, precision int) string {
    size, unit := getSizeAndUnit(size, 1000.0, decimapAbbrs)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%.*g%s", precision, size, unit)
}
```

That's why you can get the `5.57 MB` output, rather than 5573013. So if you want to get the same output as docker images command show. You can use `"github.com/docker/go-units"` to do this trick, if you want to get the accurate size, as far as I know, docker server always returns the accurate size.