# Get the size of an image using the Docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker

How do I get the size of a docker image using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)?

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
some_image : docker.models.images.Image = client.images.list()[0]
# size of some_image?
```

As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377199/how-to-get-total-size-of-a-docker-image-by-docker-api-properly), the regular docker API has some differences when getting the size from a registry or locally. I'll take either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size is listed in "attrs" json of the image.

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
some_image : docker.models.images.Image = client.images.list()[0]
some_image.attrs['Size'] # size in Bytes.
```